# How to recognize start of base64 image in mime string

Tags: image, base64, mime

In my (limited) experience with extracting the base64 image string from a mime string for my PHP based email program, the base64 image always starts after the first consecutive pair of LF (\x0A) characters in the mime string, and this always follows the mime content type, etc. Is this always the case and dependable?
Thanks!

I have not yet found an exception to this strategy but I haven´t seen a specification of this either.

For example, using the $attachment->getMimePartStr() function of php-mime-mail-parser from GitHub, I get a string:

Content-Type: image/png; name=name.png Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.png iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc.

where by using the PHP ord() function, I detect two consecutive \x0A characters filling the space between filename=name.png and iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc. that I can find with strpos() and use substr() to extract the base64 string iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc.

I want the iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc. part for the "data:" for an <img src="data: image/png; base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc.">

Comment: Do you have some examples of what you are talking about to share?

Comment: The MIME headers are followed by an empty line, then the MIME body.  If the `Content-transfer-encoding` is base64 then that body is base64-encoded, yes.

Comment: Just to clarify, a single empty line could be \n\n, but could also be \r\n\r\n; is that also a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

The standard is as you observe:

```
Content-Type: image/png; name=name.png 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.png 

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA... etc.
```

until the end of the MIME section. The content must be decoded according to the Content-Transfer-Encoding header, do not assume you'll always get base64.
However, **no**, you mustn't rely on LF only. You might get CR/LF sequences, because [they too are valid](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc822). You may want to check out [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045#page-5) among others.

For the same reason, do not assume that the base64 attachment is on a single line. Your best option, I think, is to **take everything after the headers and up to the end of the MIME section**, and for base64, remove any whitespace, then base64_decode.